# Unable to send woocommerce new order email programatically when disabled from woo-settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an automation tool inside woocommerce that i want to use to send all emails like new order/processing etc. I do not want to send woo emails from the inbuilt functionality. So i turned off the new order email in woocommerce setting.
In my automation I have added below code:

```
add_action( 'email_callback', 'email_callback' ); 
function email_callback( $args ) {  
    $email_new_order = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];
    $email_new_order->trigger( $args['order_id'] );
}
```

But this seems to trigger only if i enable new order email from woo -email-setting but that leads to send double email.

Can anyone suggest what can be done. I do not want to send duplicate email  ???

Answer (score 0):

**WC_Email_New_Order** email is triggered both by the WooCommerce email system and by your custom code. To avoid sending duplicate emails, you need to modify your custom code.

```
add_action( 'email_callback', 'email_callback' ); 
function email_callback( $args ) {  
    // Check if the New Order email is enabled in WooCommerce settings
    $new_order_email_enabled = get_option( 'woocommerce_new_order_email_enabled' );
    if ( $new_order_email_enabled == 'yes' ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $email_new_order = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];
    $email_new_order->trigger( $args['order_id'] );
}
```